# How to build a circuit that can record and playback our voice?

Tags: audio, recording

I want to build a simple circuit that can record and playback our voice. IC should be small in size and the circuit should never contain any SMD components.

Can anybody given any suggestions to build this kind of circuit.

Comment: "not SMD" and "small" are (arguably) mutually exclusive requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of minutes on digikey gives http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/ISD1730PY/ISD1730PY-ND/1133275 which is a 28-pin DIP single chip solution. Can be connected directly to buttons to operate its functions.